# BigQuery Load job treating Null as String instead of Float (json)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am loading daily data updates (json files) into bigquery table, and recent update failed with this error > **Provided Schema does not match Table project:dataset.Field splitAmount has changed type from FLOAT to STRING**.

2 files to replicate this situation with BQ UI:

Table schema was auto-created by BQ when I loaded a first json file manually using BQ UI, sample below ->

```
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "1234",  "splitAmount": null}
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "2345",  "splitAmount": 2.300}
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "3456",  "splitAmount": null}
```

second line in a file defaulted splitAmount field to FLOAT type during table creation in BQ.

second file is a subsequent update ->

```
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "1234",  "splitAmount": null}
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "2345",  "splitAmount": null}
{"objectType": "listing", "listingid": "3456",  "splitAmount": null}
```

*splitAmount is null for all records and generates error message above on loading.*

same happening when I am using BQ Python API.

How to fix it in BQ python app? (I want pipeline run on GCP and not loading data manually)

Is there a way to force schema on a load? Here is one approach I tried to force a schema (it did not work.. :cry: ), basically getting a table schema first from the existing table, and passing it as param into a jobconfig, below

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id) 
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(list_table_id) 
table = client.get_table(table_ref) 

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig() 
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 
job_config.autodetect = True 
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND 
job_config.schema = table.schema
```

Exception >> 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 13; errors: 1

Comment: Take a look here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#python

Comment: even better approach is to take a table schema (created with 1st json load) and pass it as param into a job object
```
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(list_table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)

   job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    job_config.schema = table.schema

```

Comment: this did not work either, getting exception >> 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 13; errors: 1.

Comment: sounds like you didn't defined schema correctly.

Comment: what do you mean AllenDeg? schema defined by bigquery automatically on json load.
please read description of the post - problem is in the subsequent load when ALL NULL values treated as STRINGS.

Comment: BQ seeing null assumes it's integer. Just provide the schema manually and it will work.

Comment: @AlienDeg - thanks for comment, not really helping - BQ seeing NULL assumes it's STRING not INT >> Error from above > Field splitAmount has changed type from FLOAT to STRING. > not from FLOAT to INT.. and why to change to INT if next data block will come with FLOAT and then what? change schema from INT to FLOAT?
I can fix this by inserting dummy data of FLOAT type into incoming load, but was looking for simpler way..

Anybody from BigQuery team at Google out there???